# dataframeの各セルのlistを分解して新たな変数にするには？

Tags: python, pandas

次のような各セルにリストが入ったdataframeがあります。

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': [['都営三田線/水道橋駅 歩4分', 'ＪＲ中央線/水道橋駅 歩3分'], ['東京メトロ東西線/飯田橋駅 歩5分', '東京メトロ東西線/九段下駅 歩7分', 'ＪＲ中央線/水道橋駅 歩8分'], ['ＪＲ山手線/神田駅 歩6分']]},
    index=[1, 2, 3])
```

このxを分解して、x1, x2, x3のような変数を新たに作成したいのですが、
ご教示頂けないでしょうか？

```
x1,                          x2,                        x3
都営三田線/水道橋駅 歩4分,    ＪＲ中央線/水道橋駅 歩3分,  nan
東京メトロ東西線/飯田橋駅 歩5分,  東京メトロ東西線/九段下駅 歩7分,   ＪＲ中央線/水道橋駅 歩8分
ＪＲ山手線/神田駅 歩6分,        nan,        nan
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

下記では如何でしょうか。

```
splitted = df['x'].apply(pd.Series)
splitted.columns = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3']
print(splitted)

                  x1                 x2              x3
1     都営三田線/水道橋駅 歩4分     ＪＲ中央線/水道橋駅 歩3分             NaN
2  東京メトロ東西線/飯田橋駅 歩5分  東京メトロ東西線/九段下駅 歩7分  ＪＲ中央線/水道橋駅 歩8分
3      ＪＲ山手線/神田駅 歩6分                NaN             NaN
```

Comment: 上記コマンドは、欠損値(以下の例では99999)や空白があっても動くことが分かりました。df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': [['都営三田線/水道橋駅 歩4分', 'ＪＲ中央線/水道橋駅 歩3分'], ['東京メトロ東西線/飯田橋駅 歩5分', '東京メトロ東西線/九段下駅 歩7分', 'ＪＲ中央線/水道橋駅 歩8分'], ['ＪＲ山手線/神田駅 歩6分', ''],99999,'']},